# Error 404 on Postman during POST request for a spring boot application written to implement dynamoDb functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, postman

My POST request's body is :-
{
"customerId":"123",
"rating":4,
"amountBought":1000,
"amountCancelled":100,
"amountReturned":100,
"fine":0,
"deliveryCharge":true
}
I am getting this error when sending POST request:-
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-26T11:32:57.940+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/dynamoDb"
}
The POST URL is :-http://localhost:9003/dynamoDb

I am attaching my DynamodbController.java and DynamodbRepository.java and RatingSystem.java - which is my model class

```
package com.DDB.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.DDB.model.RatingSystem;
import com.DDB.repo.DynamodbRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dynamoDb")
public class DynamodbController {

    @Autowired
    private DynamodbRepository repository;

    @PostMapping
    public String insertIntoDynamodb(@RequestBody RatingSystem brs) {
        repository.insertIntoDynamoDB(brs);
        return "Successfully inserted into DynamoDB table";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RatingSystem> getOneCustomerDetails(@RequestParam int customerId) {
        RatingSystem brs = repository.getOneCustomerDetails(customerId);
        return new ResponseEntity<RatingSystem>(brs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void updateCustomerDetails(@RequestBody RatingSystem brs) {
        repository.updateCustomerDetails(brs);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "{customerId}")
    public void deleteCustomerDetails(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId) {
        RatingSystem brs = new RatingSystem();
        brs.setCustomerId(customerId);
        repository.deleteCustomerDetails(brs);
    }
}
```

next is the repository file :-

```
package com.DDB.repo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBSaveExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ComparisonOperator;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ConditionalCheckFailedException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ExpectedAttributeValue;
import com.DDB.model.RatingSystem;

@Repository
public class DynamodbRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamodbRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public void insertIntoDynamoDB(RatingSystem brs) {
        mapper.save(brs);
    }

    public RatingSystem getOneCustomerDetails(int customerId) {
        return mapper.load(RatingSystem.class, customerId);
    }

    public void updateCustomerDetails(RatingSystem brs) {
        try {
            mapper.save(brs, buildDynamodbSaveExpression(brs));
        } catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException exception) {
            LOGGER.error("invalid data - " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void deleteCustomerDetails(RatingSystem brs) {
        mapper.delete(brs);
    }

    public DynamoDBSaveExpression buildDynamodbSaveExpression(RatingSystem brs) {
        DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
        Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected = new HashMap<>();
        expected.put("customerId", new ExpectedAttributeValue(new AttributeValue(brs.getCustomerId()))
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ));
        saveExpression.setExpected(expected);
        return saveExpression;
    }
}
```

next is the model class:-

```
package com.DDB.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "RatingSystem")
public class RatingSystem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String customerId;
    private double rating;
    private double amountBought;
    private double amountCancelled;
    private double amountReturned;
    private double fine;
    private boolean deliveryCharge;


    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "customerId")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getAmountBought() {
        return amountBought;
    }
    public void setAmountBought(double amountBought) {
        this.amountBought = amountBought;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getAmountCancelled() {
        return amountCancelled;
    }
    public void setAmountCancelled(double amountCancelled) {
        this.amountCancelled = amountCancelled;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getAmountReturned() {
        return amountReturned;
    }
    public void setAmountReturned(double amountReturned) {
        this.amountReturned = amountReturned;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public double getFine() {
        return fine;
    }
    public void setFine(double fine) {
        this.fine = fine;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public boolean isDeliveryCharge() {
        return deliveryCharge;
    }
    public void setDeliveryCharge(boolean deliveryCharge) {
        this.deliveryCharge = deliveryCharge;
    }

}
```

I have already created the table on AWS dynamodb with same attributes as in the model class.This spring boot application is also successfully running , with no errors. The console looks something like this on running :-

2m2020-04-26 17:16:33.636  INFO 9584 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DdbApplication          : Starting DdbApplication on LAPTOP-INEF3PKK with PID 9584 (C:\Users\yoin\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.0.RELEASE\DDB\target\classes started by yoin in C:\Users\yoin\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.0.RELEASE\DDB)

2020-04-26 17:16:33.639  INFO 9584 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DdbApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2020-04-26 17:16:34.367  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9003 (http)

2020-04-26 17:16:34.374  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2020-04-26 17:16:34.375  INFO 9584 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]

2020-04-26 17:16:34.465  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2020-04-26 17:16:34.465  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 792 ms

2020-04-26 17:16:34.629  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

2020-04-26 17:16:34.785  INFO 9584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9003 (http) with context path ''

2020-04-26 17:16:34.787  INFO 9584 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DdbApplication          : Started DdbApplication in 1.536 seconds (JVM running for 2.358)

Comment: show your application.propeties

Comment: i have used application.yml :-amazon:
  access:
    key: //hidden for security reasons
    secret-key: //hidden for security reasons
  region: us-east-1
  end-point:
    url: https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
server:
  port: 9003

Comment: you have no context path. so url is ok... but your reponse gave `No message available", "path": "/insert`.... you hit /insert instead of dynamoDb... check which url u hit

Comment: Ohh no, actually that's a mistake , i am using this URL :-http://localhost:9003/dynamoDb
I have updated that in the question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides @SpringBootApplication, I added @ComponentScan and @EnableAutoConfiguration annotations in the DDBApplication.java file - the java file which has the main class in it.

Comment: Try @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xxx.yyy"})